# How can I change a datagrid cell color based on conditional comparing cell values?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I'm fairly new to WPF and C#, so forgive me if this is a novice question.  I have a datagrid that's populated with values from a datatable.  For each row in the datagrid, I want to highlight a specific cell if it's value is greater than another cell's value.  For example:

```
| "A" | "B" |
|  5  |  4  | <- A[0] would be highlighted yellow
|  3  |  3  | <- A[1] would not be highlighted yellow
```

I looked at creating a bool column that would be True if A>B, then tried to map a trigger to that column in the XAML code, but I couldn't figure out how to have the setter property be assigned to a cell different than the binding.  I've also tried the following recently:

```
    foreach (DataRowView row in dgTrending.Items)
    {
      if ((int)row.Row["A"] > (int)row.Row["B"])
      {
        DataGridCell color = 
(DataGridCell)dgTrending.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(row.Row["A"]);
        color.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
      }
    }
```

For the above code, the variable color gets set to null, so I'm obviously doing something wrong there.  I know looping through each row is inefficient, but I'm hard pressed to find a better way.  Ideally I can do this through the code behind since I can't add conditionals to XAML (at least not that I've seen).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I'd advise you not to do it that way. The cells are recycled because of virtualization and you'll have no end of headaches. Use a CellStyle on the grid and set the background with Style triggers.

Comment: Is there a way to check if column "A" > "B" in XAML?  Or, is there a way to use a style trigger that has a binding on one cell, but changes the color of another?

Answer (score 0):

mvvm wpf datagrid chnage cell content Color

XMAL Code

```
    <UserControl x:Class="RetailSoft.Stock_Reports.FrmCurrentItemWiseStock"

.....


      xmlns:Converter="clr-namespace:RetailSoft.Converter"

    >



    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Converter:PositiveNegativeConverter x:Key="PositiveNegativeConverter"/>
 </UserControl.Resources>
```

DatagridColumns

```
 <DataGridTextColumn  
                    Header="Stock"
                     MinWidth="70" MaxWidth="1000"
                    x:Name="ProductName"
                    Binding="{Binding Stock}" 
                    CellStyle="{StaticResource customCellStyle}"
                    >
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}"> 
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="{Binding Stock,Converter={StaticResource PositiveNegativeConverter}}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>

                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style 
                            TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                            <Setter 
                                Property="Background" 
                                Value="SteelBlue"
                                />
                            <Setter 
                                Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" 
                                Value="Center"
                                />
                            <Setter 
                                Property="Foreground" 
                                Value="White"
                                />
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
```

and Convert class Code

```
public class PositiveNegativeConverter :  IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object Stock, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (Stock==null)
        {
            Stock = "";
        }
        string Stocks = Stock.ToString();
        bool revert = (Stocks as string).StartsWith("-");
        string stringValue = Stock as string;
        string compareValue = parameter as string;
        if (revert)
        {

            return Brushes.Tomato;

        }
        else
            return Brushes.LimeGreen;

    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```